# Importing a .Net enum into a PowerShell script

Tags: powershell, .net

Hopefully I can explain this in a clear question to avoid confusion (since I'm a bit confused myself).
I have a dll, I'll call MyCommonStuff. I have an enum object defined in a module in this assembly here:

```
MyCommonStuff\Enums\ImportEnum.cs
```

Like this:

```
namespace MyCommonStuff.ImportEnum
{
    public enum ImportType
    {
        Blah1 = 0,
        Blah2 = 1,
        Blah3 = 2
    }
}
```

I'd like to import this into a PowerShell script at run-time to avoid having to manually copy it over and have to sync it up in the event that it should change.
Could someone enlighten me on how I can go about this?

Answer (score 12):

I was trying to do something similar to this, but was defining my enum inside a custom cmdlet and it seems to work differently. Using the example provided (and assuming that the enum is tucked inside a class which extends PSCmdlet) you would need to do the following inside a powershell script/cmd window:

```
Import-Module "Path to dll"

$Blah1 = [MyCommonStuff.ImportEnum.ClassName+ImportType]::Blah1
```

For some reason you use "+" instead of "." to reference the enum value

Comment: This is exactly what I needed to get it working, the "+" is required to reference the enum

Comment: A [blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2009/08/26/plus-in-net-class-names/) about where the '+' comes from.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one possible way I foresee solving your solution.  You can create a module which is automatically loaded by powershell which adds the type for you.

To create the module, open the powershell ISE and enter the following code:

```
$Path = "path to dll"
Add-Type -Path $Path
```

Save the "module" as a .psm1 file, not a script, and name it something easy but informative.  You'll then create a new directory in the "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules" with the EXACT SAME NAME as your psm1 file.  Drop your psm1 file in there and then launch a new powershell window.

You should now be able to access your enum like so:

```
[MyCommonStuff.ImportEnum.ImportType]::Blah1
```

I'd recommend using this one module to contain all your custom types, objects, cmdlets, functions, etc so they're all in the same place.  If you do, check out the `Export-ModuleMember` cmdlet as you'll likely need it.